# How many active nodes does ethereum currently have?

Tags: nodes

[Here](https://www.ethernodes.org/network/1) shows that ethereum has nearly 33k nodes, though I'm curious how many active nodes there are?

Comment: What do you mean by active? 33k nodes sounds OK. Do you mean "active = accepting incoming connections from public"?

Comment: Hm, I'm not actually sure what the difference between active vs. non active nodes even are! However, looking at something like https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin/, there seems to be nodes that are all (41k) and then active ones (6974), so I'm curious whether there's an analogous metric for ETH